# SQL Query - Select Value from T1 where second value fully met in T2

Tags: sql

I can do this in an ugly stored procedure with temp tables and whatnot, but I know an experienced developer could do this SO much more elegantly than what I've come up with. In fact, I'd kind of rather not have to call the sproc at all, but just have one query that gives me what I need.

I'm working with two tables:

- T1 BillingDirectivesNeeded
- T2 BillingDirectives.

T1 Has two fields relevant to this task -

- PKey
- WBS1.

There will be many PKeys associated with each WBS1.

T2 has only one field of interest

- PKey.

The task I'm trying to address is geting a list of WBS1s from T1 that have ALL of their needed directives in T2 before I enable their import.

We want to import a WBS1 ONLY when all of the PKeys for that WBS1 are found in T2.  If not, I'll just leave them grayed out.

I've tried a dozen different ways to get this to happen over the last few hours, and I seem to have a mental block.   The pseudo-code would look something like this:

```
select T1.WBS1 from BillingDirectiveNeeded T1 
where [all the T1.PKeys for T1.WBS1 can be found in BillingDirectives T2]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using a `Where Exists` clause:

```
Select      T1.WBS1 
From        BillingDirectiveNeeded  T1 
Where Exists
(
    Select  1
    From    BillingDirectives   T2
    Where   T2.PKey = T1.PKey
)
```

Comment: I knew I was making this harder than it needed to be.  I coded up a little test of 15 jobs of which five were missing, and this gave me the ten that exist.  Thanks Siyual!

Answer (score 1):

```
select DISTINCT T1.WBS1 from BillingDirectiveNeeded T1 where  T1.PKey in (SELECT T2.PKey FROM BillingDirectives T2)
```